# User defined component - how to set tooltip on Component Palette?

Tags: delphi, vcl

So, I created a new component, derived from an existing TControl type.

When I installed it, it appeared on the Component Palette (is that what it's called) at the top of Delphi at design time, to allow me to add it to a form.

How do I change its tooltip text -the one that shows if I hover over the Component Palette at deign time?

Comment: Possible duplicate (second question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319276/delphi-non-visual-component-image

Comment: +1 for taking the trouble to search & post, thanks. But, please don't close it as dupe. It answers 1/2 of my question (the icon), but not the tooltip.

Comment: You should probably just remove the second question. Stack Overflow works much better when there's only one question per post.

Comment: Isn't the tool tip just the name of the component, but without the leading T? That's all it ever was in the versions I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tooltip is automatically build from the component characteristics; depending on the version of Delphi, it will be different:

- D2007:
  ClassName(Unit.Ancestor Class).
  for example: `TDataSource(Classes.TPersistent)` or `TButton(Controls.TControl)`
- D2010:

  Name: Classname
  Unit: UnitName
  Package: PackageName

like

```
Name: TButton
Unit: StdCtrls
Package: dclstd140.bpl
```

Comment: Do you have any idea where this is done in the Delphi source? I would like to change the behaviour to show the Hint property.

Comment: The tooltip is managed by the IDE itself.  You have no access to that source code, and no control over the design-time tooltips.