# How to add my icon to component in the component palette page?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delphi non visual component image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319276/delphi-non-visual-component-image)

How to add my icon to my created component in the component palette page?

Comment: Sometimes I ask questions not for me.

Comment: no i didnt know it. I just used your answer to create better answer. aaargh do you get it?

Comment: OK now I see. If that's all you wanted to do then you could have edited my answer. And you could have explained more.

Comment: @Robrok Anyway I've now voted to close this since it is an exact duplicate. I should have checked that first.

Comment: I cant delete this post. Help!

Comment: delete your answer and you should be able to delete the question

Comment: delete your answer and I should be able to delete this question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add icon to component you need to create dcr file using Delphi image editor.
In image editor create bitmap 24x24 16 bit. Rename bitmap to your control name. 
Example: TMyCustomControl - TMyCustomControl (same name)
[image]
Save dcr file in the folder where the package is with any name (example: Icon.dcr). 
Then open your package and right click -> View source.
 
Add line :
{$R 'The dcr filename'}
In this case:
`{$R 'Icon.dcr'}`
Click Compile and Install.
 
There you go. You have created your own component with icon. :)
[image]

Comment: this is much better and easier explanation than the "possible duplicate" question's answer

Answer (score 2):

- Create a .dcr file in the Delphi Image Editor.
- Add a bitmap to this with the same name as your control. It needs to be 24 pixels square, and use 16 colours.
- Link this .dcr, which is really just a resource file, to your package with a $R in your .dpk for example.